# Mass Add to Campaign Button on Custom Object List View

Tags: custom-object, custom-button, campaign-member

I have created an "Add to Campaign" button on a custom object which when you click it takes you to the Add Members page, so that part correct.  However, when I try to select records and click the button I get this error message: -

Unable to Access Page
The value of the "ids" parameter contains a character that is not allowed or the value exceeds the maximum allowed length. Remove the character from the parameter value or reduce the value length and resubmit. If the error still persists, report it to our Customer Support team. Provide the URL of the page you were requesting as well as any other related information.

This is the formula used: -

https://na1.salesforce.com/ui/campaign/MassAddCMFromListingWizard?ent=contact&retURL=%2F003%3Ffcf%3D00B30000006FV3J&wizardRetUrl=%2F003%3Ffcf%3D00B30000006FV3J&macmflw_idSourceType=List&macmflw_memberType=Contact&

My custom object is called Job and the contact field (lookup) is Job_Contact.  Any assistance would be gratefully appreciated.